# Python/BeautifulSoup - how to assign html code to variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How i can assign html code to a variable so later I could refer to it?

Example:

```
"div class='test'" - some html code



some_variable = "'div', {'class': ='test'}" *#assigning above to the variable*

print(soup.find(some_variable)) *# is not working*
print(soup.find('div', {"class": 'test'}) # **is working**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your search parameters inside dictionary and then use `**`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''
<div class="test">This I want</div>
<div class="other">This I dont want</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

params = {'name': 'div', 'attrs': {'class': 'test'}}
    
print( soup.find(**params).text )
```

Prints:

```
This I want
```

---

Or: Use CSS selector:

```
selector = 'div.test'

print( soup.select_one(selector).text )
```

Comment: wow, thanks! good to see 2 solutions, but i think i ll stick to selector as it is more clearly for person who reads :P

Comment: @zarize, for reference, the `**params` syntax is called ["parameter unpacking"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/), and it essentially "unpacks" the dict `params` into the keyword parameters of the `soup.find` function.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

I just wonder now... what if i would like to add .text method at the end of the selector?

selector = 'div.test'.text wouldnt work of course

but i would like to keep possibility to add dynamic method, how to achieve it?